# Returning status code in laravel

Tags: http, exception, laravel, response, status

I am a total noob at Laravel

```
public function stageFiles($user, $project) {
    try
    {
        $path = Input.get("item");
    } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $exceptionMessage = $e->getMessage();
        $responseText = json_encode($exceptionMessage);
    }
}
```

What I want to do is return the response text and a status code, 500, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you send a 500:

```
public function stageFiles($user, $project) {
    try
    {
        $path = Input.get("item");
    } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $exceptionMessage = $e->getMessage();
        $responseText = json_encode($exceptionMessage);

        return Response::make($responseText, 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: GREAT!! This is exactly what I ended up doing but I had no idea if it is correct, I appreciate the assistance.